# PHP - Difference between break and continue in switch case

Tags: php, switch-statement, break, continue

What is the different between

```
switch (variable) {
        case 'value':
        # code...
        break;

        case 'value':
        # code...
        break;
}
```

and this one

```
switch (variable) {
        case 'value':
        # code...
        continue;

        case 'value':
        # code...
        continue;
}
```

It's really different result or just same?

Comment: Read the note in the manual of [continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php), or just the entire thing..

Comment: If you want code to execute when the case matches more than 1 value, you still use "break";   case "value1": and underneath it) case "value2": then  under that -- the code to execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example code with both the switch cases mentioned above

```
<?php
    $variable = 20;
    echo "Normal<br/>";
    switch ($variable) {
        case '20':
            echo "twenty";
        break;
        case '21':
            echo "twenty one";
        break;
    }

    echo "<br/><br/>With Continue<br/>";
    switch ($variable) {
        case '20':
            echo "twenty";
        continue;
        case '21':
            echo "twenty one";
        continue;
    }
?>
```

When I execute above code I got following output

```
Normal
twenty

With Continue
twenty
```

How?

Working of break statement

[Break statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) causes code execution to come out of the block and execute next statements because of which switch statement will execute only one case statement and exit out of switch block without executing other case blocks.

Working of Continue statement

[Continue statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) in case of loops will cause loop to stop execution of current iteration of loop and go for next iteration of the loop(if any exists) but in case of switch statement it is considered as a loop statement but no next iterations causing exit switch statement.

We can have a switch statement without break statements too like this

```
<?php
    $variable = 20;
    echo "Normal";
    switch ($variable) {
        case '19':
            echo "<br/>Nineteen";
        case '20':
            echo "<br/>twenty";
        case '21':
            echo "<br/>twenty one";
        case '23':
            echo "<br/>twenty three";
    }
?>
```

The output of above code will be

```
Normal
twenty
twenty one
twenty three
```

i.e. executing all the case statements after the case where first match is found.

Comment: You should update your answer as the official documentation states that: *in PHP the switch statement is considered a looping structure for the purposes of continue. continue behaves like break (when no arguments are passed).*

Answer (score 2):

This is a special case for PHP because, as stated by the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php):

> Note: In PHP the switch statement is considered a looping structure
>   for the purposes of continue. continue behaves like break (when no
>   arguments are passed). If a switch is inside a loop, continue 2 will
>   continue with the next iteration of the outer loop.

So in essence it means there is no actual difference between your two examples. However for clarity I think it would be best to use `break` as that is the standard in other languages. Note also that you could use `continue 2` (or 3, 4...) to advance to the next iteration of a loop if the switch is inside a loop (or more).

Answer (score 1):

In PHP the above two codes work in same way. Here the `break` and `continue` statement prevent control going to next `case`. That is the `continue` acts just like `break` here. Also switch is intended to be executed only once. It's not a loop. Hence `continue` is not relevant here.

Note:If there is loop enclosing this `switch` statement then the result will be different.